# Объединение меток [сборка] и [build]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть такие метки:

- [build](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build) (188 вопросов)
- [сборка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0) (190 вопросов)

Надо их синонимизировать/объединить.

Comment: А почему? Сборка — это не только процесс, но ещё и бинарный пакет. Эти сущности всё же могут рассматриваться отдельно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Прочитайте описание меток.

Comment: @Зонтик описание описанием, надо и на реальное использование смотреть.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ для любителей бинарных пакетов нужно завести отдельную метку :)

Comment: @Зонтик и значит, перетегировать актуальные вопросы сначала.